Fokker-Planck Equation on Strip and its Inverse Problem
Suppose we have a Fokker-Planck Equation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $f$ unknown.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\Delta \rho - \nabla\cdot(f\rho)
\end{equation}
With boundary condition:
\begin{align}
\rho(x,0) = \rho_{0}(x)\\
\lim_{\vert x\vert \rightarrow \infty}\rho(t,x)  =0\\
\lim_{\vert x\vert \rightarrow \infty}| \nabla\rho(t,x)|  =0
\end{align}
And observed snapshot $$\rho_{1}(x) = \rho(x,1).$$
Is there any characterization of  $f$ which makes all the conditions above possible? $f$ shall be the function of $x$ but not $t$.
I'd be appreciate if you provide with me some related materials if the answer is too complicated, since I'm not familiar with parabolic equations, thank you.

Are you sure about the boundary conditions? Can you really impose the solution at both initial and final time? Having just first order derivatives with respect to $t$ would suggest otherwise.

@PierreCarre So perhaps it's not a matter of existence of solution but more like a inverse problem question?

I think that what @PierreCarre is saying is that there is no solution for your problem in the way you stated it. Is yours the correct statement?

@Jon is correct, I think that the proposed set of boundary conditions does not yield a well-posed problem. The solution is determined just by fixing $\rho(x,0)=\rho_0(x)$, hence, either $\rho(x,1)=\rho_1(x)$ and the condition is useless, or $\rho(x,1) \ne \rho_1(x)$ and the problem does not have a solution.

@Jon Yes I understand, what i really what to ask is: for a Fokker-Planck Equation, with known initial condition $\rho_{0}(x)$ and observed snapshot $\rho_{1}(x)$, what can we say about $f(x)$, I wonder if there is a complete characterize of $f$, I'll edit the question ,thanks.

And $f$ is unknown.

Is there something you know about $f$? Normally, such $f$ would come from some constitutive law and would also satisfy  some pde.

Also, I'm not sure if it helps, but this can be written as a conservation law
$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot(\frac 12 \nabla \rho - f \rho)$$

@PierreCarre Nothing except that it should be in a proper Sobolev Space? I found a paper named The Variational Formulation of the Fokker--Planck Equation, which may describe the lower bound of $\int_{0}^{1}|f|^{2}\rho\mathrm{d}t$, I'll read it and post my discoveries here if it helps. Thank you!
